# Tkinter allow rows to fill the vertical space on window resize

Tags: tkinter

I have a tkinter app with three main horizontal areas:

1. header
2. a series of labels and entries
3. a row of buttons

The app works perfectly when I resize the window horizontally:

1. the  header remain in the center
2. the entries expand to fill the allotted space
3. the *Save* button stays on the left and the *Cancel* button on the right

But when I resize vertically I am happy that:

1. the header stays at the top
2. the buttons stay at the bottom

But, I would like the entries to spread out in some proportional way to fill the remaining space instead of clumping together in the centre. Is this possible?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

PAD = 5


def _header_frame(container):
    frame = ttk.Frame(container)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    header = ttk.Label(frame, text='Header', font=('Arial', 16))
    header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.EW, padx=PAD)


def _main_frame(container):
    frame = ttk.Frame(container, style='red.TFrame')
    frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)

    frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
    frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=5)

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text='label 1')
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NE, padx=PAD)

    entry = ttk.Entry(frame)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW, padx=PAD)

    padding = ttk.Label(frame, text='')
    padding.grid(row=1, column=0)

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text='label 2')
    label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.SE, padx=PAD)

    entry = ttk.Entry(frame)
    entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.EW, padx=PAD)

    padding = ttk.Label(frame, text='')
    padding.grid(row=3, column=0)

    label = ttk.Label(frame, text='label 3')
    label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.SE, padx=PAD)

    entry = ttk.Entry(frame)
    entry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.EW, padx=PAD)


def _button_frame(container) -> None:
    """Create button row."""
    frame = ttk.Frame(container)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.EW, padx=PAD, pady=PAD)

    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
    frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    process_button = ttk.Button(
        frame,
        text='Save',
    )
    process_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    padding = ttk.Label(frame, text='')
    padding.grid(row=0, column=1)

    quit_button = ttk.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=dismiss)
    quit_button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.E)


def dismiss():
    root.grab_release()
    root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()

# style = ttk.Style()
# style.configure('TFrame', background='yellow')
# style.configure('blue.TFrame', background='blue')
# style.configure('green.TFrame', background='green')
# style.configure('red.TFrame', background='red')

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

_header_frame(root)
_main_frame(root)
_button_frame(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to configure row 1 of the root window to be sticky to all four edges of the space allocated to it.

Next, if you want the rows spread out then you need to give the same non-zero weight to every row.

Lastly, you might want to remove the custom padding for the label and entry, since padding will happen automatically, though you can keep it in if you want extra padding. Also, you need to adjust the `sticky` value to either be the same or remove it altogether. You can also remove the extra labels that you use for padding.

Personally I find layout issues to be easier to solve when all of the layout code is together. The end result looks like this:

```py
def _main_frame(container):
    frame = tk.Frame(container, bg="pink")
    frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.rowconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1)
    frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=5)

    label1 = ttk.Label(frame, text='label 1')
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(frame)

    label2 = ttk.Label(frame, text='label 2')
    entry2 = ttk.Entry(frame)

    label3 = ttk.Label(frame, text='label 3')
    entry3 = ttk.Entry(frame)

    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

    label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

    label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
```

Here is a screenshot with the window expanded from its original size so you can see how the widgets are evenly spaced.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it was "configure row 1 of the root window to be sticky to all four edges" that I needed - all the other weird stuff was just a drowning man thrashing. Thanks :)

Comment: I like the construction 
    rows = tuple(range(3));
    frame.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1) - didn't know you could so that!